# Generic Java function - return generic value

Tags: java, generics, java-8, binary-tree

I'm currently writing a simple binary tree that consists of `Node<T>` Objects.

`Node<T>` has these properties:

```
private T value = null;
private Node<T> left = null;
private Node<T> right = null;
```

Currently there are getters and setters for all three.

My question is:

If I add an enum that specifies which side/value of a node i want to access, like:

```
public static enum Sides {LEFT, RIGHT, VALUE};
```

Would it be possible to define a generic getter and setter?

I already tried something like this:

```
public <E> get(Side side) {
    switch(side){
        case LEFT:
            return (E)this.left;
        [...]
    }
}
```

Is this the only way to do it, or are there better ones?

And how would I define the setter?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You could but why would you want to do that? Note that you shouldn't have to have a setter by the way. A Node could be immutable.

Comment: Getting the left or right child is completely different from getting the value. Whatever you do, **don't try to make a VALUE option**.

Comment: @Tunaki Why would you make `Node` immutable? That would force a lot of copying new nodes, all the way up to the root node, when adding or removing a leaf node.

Comment: @Andreas It would yes but it would also allow ease parallelization.

Comment: @Tunaki Correct, *assuming* that multi-threading support is required, or even desired. Adding complexity and performance degradation for the sake of concurrency, when nothing in the question suggests such requirement, is not at all useful. A blanket comment like that, without mentioning why or under what circumstances immutability is good, is misguided, in my opinion.

Comment: @Andreas That's why I said "it could" ;).

Comment: @Tunaki Sorry. I was focused on the "shouldn't".

Comment: @Andreas: copying nodes up to the root isn’t that expensive. For a balanced tree, it’s `O(log(n))`. But it removes the need for copying the entire tree defensively for protection against potential modifications at other places. That’s not only a multi-threading issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't want to have separate getters and setters for each side (in reality I probably would), and I did want mutability (in reality I probably wouldn't), I'd do

```
public enum Sides {LEFT, RIGHT}; // FYI static is redundant for inner enums

public Node<T> get(Side side) {
    switch(side) {
        ...
    }
}

public void set(Side side, Node<T> node) {
    switch(side) {
        ...
    }
}

public T getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(T value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are deciding at runtime depending on the current SIDE what type will be returned. Generics are used for type check safety at compile time, not at runtime.

You have two options.

- Using Object (without generics)
- Create an holder object that can hold Node and non-Node types if you want to use generics. And return the generic holder object.